# Insert data into bfile column

Tags: sql, oracle, types, ora-00932

Hi I am trying to insert data into a bfile column with below code:

```
1.) CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY
STUFF
AS
'D:/Dev/stuff';
```

---

```
2.) create table temp_bfile
(
bfile_loc    BFILE
);
```

---

```
3.)insert into temp_bfile(bfile_loc) values (BFILENAME('STUFF', 'WD.pdf'));
```

---

```
4.) select * from temp_bfile;
```

The fourth block of code throws me this error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got FILE
```

What I am missing here ? Using Oracle 10g XE on windows 7

Comment: Got from documentation: IF an object not intended for normal use, then do not access the restricted object. I guess that should be the answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need the 11g (or 11gr2) client to [display BLOB / BFILE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/whatsnew.htm)